# Retry on the next Flux element and omit the successful ones

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

A little background.

I am trying to use reactive programming to be able to download file from the other service. The trick is that in case of connection failure or failed Flux element (anything) I would like to retry on the Flux a number of times **but** once being able to grasp on it I would like to resume without processing the elements from the very start.

What I mean is that, something goes wrong and I got only 56 elements from my Flux out of 100 possible (let's say it's an image in .jpg) because of the connection failure. Once I successfully retry I would like to resume on **57th** element so I do not have to process it and perform **GET** from the start once again.

Here is how the normal retry looks like:
[image: Flux retry()]

but what I would like to achieve is that on retry I would only have to get the red colored element (as I already have yellow and purple).

Just a sidenote, I would like to achieve the functionality as with [HTTP range request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) where I can get bytes in specific range only and in case of failure I would be able to resume from the byte I want.

Is that even possible what I am trying to achieve? If so, what could be the possible course of action?

Comment: The simplest solution would be keeping track of how much data you've already downloaded for certain Flux elements (or range). On the next retry, you can just skip the elements that are already downloaded.

Comment: @Sarowar and this question is about **how** to skip those elements that are already downloaded

Comment: I'm guessing you'll be using WebClient to make the request. But before request, (re-)evaluate the range if you really need to make the request and update the status every time you finish downloading. In the next retry, you can check the updated status(re-evaluate). You'll get all element on each retry, simply choose not to process already processed elements.
I think the answer by Simon Baslé means the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep some state (the beginning of the range to request, at least) on a per-subscriber basis. That has to be done upstream of the `retry`, so that each retry re-evaluates the range. At the same time, the state should be atomically updatable AND visible downstream of the `retry` (for updating purposes). I'm assuming you're using `WebClient`:

- a `flatMap` can be used to create a scope in which the range state is visible
- in the lambda, an `AtomicLong` can be used as the state
- again in the flatmap lambda, wrap the webclient call in a `Flux.defer` to ensure lazy creation of the request with re-evaluation of the state for generating the appropriate header (reading from the `AtomicLong`)
- append `retry` after the `defer`
- update the `AtomicLong` as needed once each piece is received and processed (eg. in a `doOnNext`)